# XMl: I have a xml file of one schema, i want to convert this xml file to another xml file with different naming convention

Tags: xml

I have a xml file of one schema, i want to convert this xml file to another xml file with different naming convention (the element tag names would be changed in the new xml file)

for ex: xml file which i have is of following type

```
'<Parent>
 <Child Name = "C1" attribute1 = "true">
   <Sibbling Name ="one" />
   <Sibbling Name ="two" />
</Child>
</Parent>'
```

now this i want to change to a diff naming convention,
`<CustomXMLFile> 
     <InnerElement Name = "C1" >
       <CustomAttribute Name= "attribute1" value = "true">
     </InnerElement>
 </CustomXMLFile>`

//parent should be as CustomXMLFile  in new file 
//Child should be as InnerElement in new file
//attribute1 should be configured as inner node

Comment: So what do you want to do? Whats your question?

Comment: I don't see your question. But it sounds like a job for XSLT.

Comment: You might want to look at XSLT.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to convert XML files from one dialect to another is through [XSLT](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/).